# What was Eddie's long-term goal in Limitless?

Tags: plot-explanation, limitless

In *Limitless* (the 2011 movie, not the TV show), Eddie Mora starts to take NZT and comes to some sort of epiphany where he formulates a long term plan. However, it's not clear to me what that plan actually is. First, Eddie attempts to make money in the stock market. Then he plans to merge two companies (the largest merger ever). And then by the end

> Eddie runs for for US Senator, and Van Loon implies that he will eventually be President.

However, it's not clear to me what Eddie's actual goal turned out to be. I suppose he simply wants to eventually be in a high-position political office, but to what end? What does Eddie hope to accomplish by doing that? And how does brokering a merger between two companies fit into this plan? Does he just want to make more money?

Comment: It is purposely left unrevealed. That is one thing about the show that bothered me the first time I watched it. He has this moment of epiphany and they make this big deal out of it, but then it is never really addressed again.

Comment: @sanpaco Sorry for the confusion, I had meant the movie, not the new TV  show. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: I was referring to the movie as well. When I said show I didn't mean "tv show". Although it is good to clarify. Actually I was also going to add that the tv show has bothered me in that they didn't address Eddie's epiphany or what he is doing about it. Instead there's a new character who solves crimes. Like we don't have enough shows about unique characters solving crimes.

Comment: I love "Limitless" (the movie). Before your question, I never realized that Eddie may have earned all that money in order to run a successful (expensive) political campaign. After becoming president, I have no idea what is plans are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This a conversation from the *Limitless* TV show (episode 6) not the movie, but it could explain his motives

> **Eddie Morra:** This rice contains a complete nutritional profile. Everything the human body needs. It can grow in the harshest environments. Places we need it the most. With a little more research, this rice could feed the entire world.
>
> **Brian Finch:** I don't understand. Why can't you tell anyone about it? I mean, if that's true, why aren't you shouting it from the rooftops?
>
> **Eddie Morra:** Because people won't want it. I make an announcement. Lobbyists bring it to action. People rave over GMO's and it's buried. Science can't change the world on its own. The world needs to be willing to change. And it takes leaders. Leaders who are willing to chip away at the obstacles, cut through the noise and play the game. And win the game.

Answer (score 3):

To make the world a better place, of course,  make substantial changes. What a truly smart person would do, makes sense.
Becoming the President would have given him the opportunity to do so.

Comment: You might want to add documentation to support your answer, something in the move that correlates with what you're saying.

Comment: What evidence is there that Eddie's goal was "to make a world a better place"? It didn't seem to me like he had such altruistic intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Eddie morra wanted free access to an unlimited supply of limitless pills.  Freedom to be unlimited forever.  He was always running out of pills, and his struggle over the movie is to free himself from this constraint, which is the only constraint he has.
After his epiphany he says.."but I'll need money to do that".

Comment: I don't think that this matches up with what we see in the movie. Eddie already has a plan to get more of the drug by offering the lab tech money to replicate it. However, becoming senator with an eye on the presidency doesn't really further a goal of getting more pills, especially since running a campaign is very costly.

Comment: @Thunderforge, also, the higher profile he became, the harder it would be to hide his pill consumption and procurement. If he just wanted more pills, he'd probably want to stay lower profile.